# nginx index directive works fine locally but gives 404 on ec2

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a web project that I want to deploy using docker-compose and nginx.

Locally, I:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

If I `docker-compose up`, I can access `localhost/` and get redirected to my `index.html`.

Now on my ec2 instance (a regular ec2 instance where I installed docker and docker-compose) I `docker-compose pull`, then docker-compose up.
All the containers launch correctly and I can `exec sh` into my nginx container and see there's a `/facebook/index.html` file.

- If I go to `[instance_ip]/index.html`, everything works as expected.
- If I go to `[instance_ip]/`, I get a 404 response.
  nginx receives the request (I see it in the access logs) but does not redirect to `index.html`.

Why is the `index` directive not able to redirect to my `index.html` file?

I tried to:

- Reproduce locally by remove all local images and pulling from my registry.
- Kill my ec2 instance and launch a new one.

But I got the same result.
I'm using docker-compose 1.11.1 and docker 17.05.0. On the ec2 instance it's docker 17.03.1 and I tried both docker-compose 1.11.1 and 1.14.1 (Sign that I'm a bit desperate ;)).

An extract from my docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
    image: [image from registry]
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: deploy/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

My nginx image starts from alpine, installs nginx, adds the index.html file and copies my conf file in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Here's my nginx config. I checked that it is present on the running containers (both locally and on ec2).

```
# prevent from exiting when using `run` to launch container
daemon off;
worker_processes auto;
#
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings

    sendfile off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/file.log debug;

        listen          80 default_server;

        # root            /home/domain.com;

        # Bad developers use underscore in headers.
        underscores_in_headers on;

        # root should be out of location block
        root /facebook;
        location / {
            index index.html;
            # autoindex on;
            try_files $uri @app;
        }

        location @app {
            include uwsgi_params;
            # Using docker-compose linking, the nginx docker-compose service depends on a 'web' service.
            uwsgi_pass web:3033;
        }

    }
}
```

I have no idea why the container is behaving differently on the ec2 instance.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Docker Nginx logs, does it show any error details with 404?

Comment: Nothing there or in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: And `/var/log/nginx/file.log` ?

Comment: Only lines like 'closed connection with ip address...'. I think it's normal since 404 is not seen as an error by nginx. I only see that I get a 404 in the `access.log`

Comment: I think changing `try_files $uri @app;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ @app;` should do the job for you

Comment: Sorry I just realized this was due to a totally different issue... I'm using vue-cli for the frontend and I picked a progressive web app template. Which caused my browser to cache the files, and tricked me into believing nginx was serving my content...  
As for the nginx config I moved the `try_files` to a different `location /` block and changed the first `location /` to `location = /`.  
This works, the way I understand it `index` causes an internal redirect and the request goes on to the next block (with changed uri now pointing to the index.html). Thanks for your help (and sorry ;))!